# extracting data from matchobjects

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I have a long sequence with multiple repeats of a specific string( 'say GAATTC') randomly throughout the sequence string. I'm currently using the regular expression .span() to provide with me with the indices of where the pattern 'GAATTC' is found. Now I want to use those indices to slice the pattern between the G and A (i.e. 'G|AATTC').

How do I use the data from the match object to slice those out?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is replace the 'GAATTC' by the 'G|AATTC' one (not sure of what you want to do in the end), I think that you can manage this without regex:

```
>>> string = 'GAATTCAAGAATTCTTGAATTCGAATTCAATATATA'
>>> string.replace('GAATTC', 'G|AATTC')
'G|AATTCAAG|AATTCTTG|AATTCG|AATTCAATATATA'
```

EDIT: ok, this way can be adapted to suit what you want to do:

```
>>> groups = string.replace('GAATTC', 'G|AATTC').split('|')
>>> groups
['G', 'AATTCAAG', 'AATTCTTG', 'AATTCG', 'AATTCAATATATA']
>>> map(len, groups)
[1, 8, 8, 6, 13]
```

Comment: I don't want to replace it with a '|'. I want to find it within a given string (where it can be found multiple times), slice it between the G and AATTC, and then count the lengths of each fragment along with the adjacent sequences.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have the string and an index where the sequence `GAATTC` starts, so do you need this (`i` here is the `m.start` for the group)?

```
>>> seq = "GAATTC"
>>> s = "AATCCTGAGAATTCAAC"
>>> i = 8    # the index where seq starts in s
>>> s[i:]
'GAATTCAAC'
>>> s[i:i+len(seq)]
'GAATTC'
```

That extracts it. You can also slice the original sequence at the `G` like this:

```
>>> s[:i+1]
'AATCCTGAG'
>>> s[i+1:]
'AATTCAAC'
>>>
```